# How to get the exact time of market open and market close

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

I want to get the exact time of marketclose & maketopen.

Each Value must be stored in their own respective time-based variables for further calculations

```
//@version=5

indicator('time market open close', overlay=true, precision=1)

market_open = time(

market_close = time

plot(market_open )  // the stock market starts


plot(market_close ) //  the stock market  ends for the day
```

**MY ENTIRE CODE FOR MANY INDICATORS HAS COMPLETED BEEN HALTED BASED ON THIS ISSUE**

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the open/close times of your ticker.
You can find out more about date/time formatting in the [User manual on Time](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Time.html).

```
//@version=5
indicator('time market open close', overlay=true, precision=1)

var string  dateTimeFormat = "{0,time,full}"
var color   myColor        = color.new(color.yellow, 70)

var int market_open  = na
var int market_close = na

newDay = dayofmonth != dayofmonth[1]

if newDay
    market_open  := time
    market_close := time_close[1]

if barstate.islast
    market_open_str  = str.format(dateTimeFormat, market_open)
    market_close_str = str.format(dateTimeFormat, market_close)
    label_str        = 'open : ' + market_open_str + '\nclose : ' + market_close_str
    label.new(bar_index, close, label_str, style=label.style_label_left)

bgcolor(newDay ? myColor : na) // show start of a new day
```

Which yields

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have used the code, `market_close` does not work. Everything else is perfect
How do I resolve the issue?
The above plotted is only market open and not market close

Comment: **There is an overlap of open and close.** Below code verifies the same. Kindly add to above indicator

`line.new(market_open, open, market_open, close, xloc=xloc.bar_time, style=line.style_dashed,extend=extend.both, width = 3 , color = myColor)`


`line.new(market_close, open, market_close, close, xloc=xloc.bar_time, style=line.style_dashed,extend=extend.both, width = 3 , color = color.green)`